# How many SHA256 hashes can a single thread compute?

Tags: hashpower, asic, sha256, antminer

ASICs use many threads to compute SHA256 hash functions in parallel.
At the time of this post, Antminer S19 can compute 110TH/s.
How many SHA256 hash functions per thread can the best SHA256 ASIC compute?

I would like to know the maximum number of iterative hashes per second, i.e.,
SHA256^N(s) = SHA256(SHA256(....(SHA256(s)))) that can be computed on the best hardware.

Comment: There's no "threads" in an ASIC, and bitcoin miners don't compute SHA256 at all, they do partial fragments of the end of one, and the start of another, never the whole thing.

Comment: Also Bitcoin mining does not involve iterated hashing, so ASICs are almost certainly incapable of that.